# Error: Failed to instantiate provider "aws" to obtain schema: timeout while waiting for plugin to start

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting this error when applying or planning terraform

> Error: Failed to instantiate provider "aws" to obtain schema: timeout while waiting for plugin to start

Terraform init works.
Last time I was able to fix it by restarting my computer but now, it didn't work.

I tried very simple code to test but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could get a solution adding a new rule on the security group that allow connect to my eks on AWS. In my case my IP change and I forgot adding for this reason I got the error.